# shutil copyfile giving Errno 2 on my destination folder

Tags: python, file-transfer, shutil

I have written a function like below:

```
def separate_files(filetree_list, destination):

    from shutil import copyfile
    from os import makedirs
    from os.path import join, exists, commonprefix
    
    try:
        for file in filetree_list:
            dst = join(destination,
                       '\\'.join(file.split(commonprefix(filetree_list))[1].split('\\')[0:-1]))
            if not exists(dst):
                print(dst, " doesn`t exist. Creating...")
                makedirs(dst)
                print(exists(dst), ". Path created.")
            print(file)
            copyfile(file, dst)
    except:
        print("Moving files has FAILED.")
    else:
        print("Moving files was SUCCESSFUL.")
```

When I call it with a "filetree_list" list containing a single element and destination prepared with os.path.join:

```
filetree_list = ['C:\\Users\\<username>\\staging_folder\\folder_1\\filename.xlsx'] 
destination = os.path.join(staging_dir, 'Sorted', 'Unwanted_files')
```

I get the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-29-c3525a60c859> in <module>()
     14         print(exists(dst), ". Path created.")
     15     print(file)
---> 16     copyfile(file, dst)

    C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\shutil.py in copyfile(src, dst, follow_symlinks)
    119     else:
    120         with open(src, 'rb') as fsrc:
--> 121             with open(dst, 'wb') as fdst:
    122                 copyfileobj(fsrc, fdst)
    123     return dst

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\<username>\\staging_folder\\Sorted\\Unwanted_files\\'
```

What is strange about it (and it is driving me insane at the moment), is that this folder definitely exists, and has been created by the "if not exists(dst)" block in separate_files function - I can even see it in the Windows Explorer!

To add insult to injury, when I run this function with the same destination argument but multiple strings in a list, it does what I expect and there are no errors!

Can anyone offer any insight into what am I doing wrong in here?

Comment: Ooops, sorry - a leftover from the function prototyping stage. Obviously, it should be copyfile(file, dst) in there, rather than the copyfile(file, join(destination, file.split(commonprefix(filetree_list))[1])) one. I`ll edit that change in now.

Comment: Updated the loop problem as well - sorry for that, I blame my bad copying from IDE skills.

Comment: `dst` is a folder name. `with open(dst, 'wb')` is trying to open it as a file (for writing). That can't work.

Comment: Umm, but isn`t the destination argument supposed to be a folder, rather than a file? Source points to a file, while dst points to a folder where this file is supposed to land?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html#shutil.copyfile:

> `shutil.copyfile(src, dst, *, follow_symlinks=True)`
>
> Copy the contents (no metadata) of the file named *`src`* to a file named *`dst`* and return *`dst`*. *`src`* and *`dst`* are path names given as strings. ***`dst`* must be the complete target file name; look at [`shutil.copy()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html#shutil.copy) for a copy that accepts a target directory path.**

You're trying to pass a directory as `dst` to `copyfile`. That doesn't work.

Comment: Thank you - that fixed it for me. I modified the copyfile line to
copyfile(file, os.path.join(dst, filename)) and all is fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

noted one thing, if the file path is large than 259 character, it will give same error.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32024412)